# What is a "MOD" and how does it differ from a "MOC"?

Tags: moc, terminology, afol, set-modification

In [this imgur post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82Qmn.jpg), one of the images is captioned "MODs and MOCs - Ocean Beach, Kingsman Tailor shop, Sanctum Santorum."

If a "MOC" is a "My Own Creation," what is (the most commonly used definition of) a "MOD"?

[This thread on Eurobrick](https://www.eurobricks.com/forum/index.php?/forums/topic/49417-mod/) suggests that "MOD" could stand for "My Own Design" (which might or might not be different from "MOC"), or could just be a relatively minor "MODification" of an existing set.

I didn't see a consensus over there, and I don't see the question raised on StackExchange yet, so I thought I'd ask StackExchange. **What's a MOD?** And when would you use that term instead of "MOC"?

Answer (score 10):

It's MODification, "My Own Design" is silly.
Also used quite extensively outside of the LEGO community, e.g. in gaming a MOD is altered game code you execute, either to cheat or to change graphics for fun.

So an existing set where you altered things to is a MOD.

A MOC is created from scratch.

Comment: I agree with this. Mods are likely easier to get started with. Altering an oceanic research vessel into a warship by taking out the laboratory equipment and adding cannons and missile launchers would be a mod. This is certainly a lot easier than making your own warship from scratch.