# Which current wave (2018 onwards) Harry Potter set should I buy to make 12 Grimmauld Place?

Tags: sets, alternate-model, activity-support, harry-potter

I would really want LEGO to make an official model of 12 Grimmauld Place, the magical house in London used by the Order of the Phoenix.

[image]

As this building is rather dim and uninteresting from the outside, I doubt it will ever be released as a set by LEGO. There hasn’t been a set depicting any scene from inside or outside of Grimmauld Place in any of the Harry Potter waves according to [Brickset](https://brickset.com/sets?query=Harry%20potter).

My question is, if I really want to make 12 Grimmauld Place, which single current wave set can I buy to get as close as possible? Are there any websites that show alternative versions of LEGO models?

Comment: https://ideas.lego.com/projects/cee8986e-6cf6-4706-b4d4-2f79418db20a shows a user generated project.
Also, it might help when searching to look for 12 Grimmauld place.

Comment: @Ben thanks for pointing out the mistake in the number, I have corrected it in both the question and the answer. That Ideas submission doesn’t resemble Grimmauld Place very much though ...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Indeed, there haven’t been any models of 12 Grimmauld Place as of yet, and even though the house features in a number of memorable scenes in the movies, even those scenes have never been depicted in an official LEGO model since the inception of the theme 20 years ago. I am still keeping my hopes up this will be a set, perhaps even including the folding motion to make it appear magically! One can only hope ....

It is actually quite common to turn official LEGO models into alternate builds, even if the set is not an official 2-in-1 or 3-in-1 model. This is called a MOD (covered in [this question here on this site](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/14530/what-is-a-mod-and-how-does-it-differ-from-a-moc)). A famous one in the AFOL world is the [MOD that turns 10214 Tower Bridge into a proper Modular Building](https://rebrickable.com/mocs/MOC-11989/InyongBricks/10214-tower-bridge-alternative-build/#details).

There are several websites that feature MOD designs. The best known one is [Rebrickable](https://www.rebrickable.com), where AFOLs can upload designs for any set (including MODs) and allow people to match up the pieces in their collection to the design, sell the instructions etc.

Another well-known site is Eurobricks, where scattered throughout the vast amount of forums and threads you can search for [MOD] in a posting title and find a lot of examples of MODs.

Back to the question: To make 12 Grimmauld place you need a set with lots of windows, 1xN bricks and a door. Looking at what sets are currently available, I think set [75980: Attack on the Burrow](https://brickset.com/sets/75980-1/Attack-on-The-Burrow) is a good candidate.

[image]

As you can see, it has lots of bricks including masonry profile bricks, as well as windows and a door.

I went ahead and tried to build 12 Grimmauld Place. Here is what I built using only pieces from 75980. Did I come close enough?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: A really neat trick would be if you can get it to fold in on itself like the movie version.  You'd kind of have to make it only the front facade and not the interior for that to work, of course...

Answer (score 3):

The Brothers Brick just published notification of **another** unrelated build - this one is finally an official set. (Though the set number being 76xxx and not being a superhero set is surprising.)

[image: set 76408]

Comment: I'm willing to consolidate all 3 independent builds into one answer, although I wonder if it would be best to just delete the previous, unofficial builds, because re-reading the question today makes it seem like this is really the best answer of all.

Answer (score 1):

Lego just put this unofficial build on Facebook today: [12 Grimmauld](https://www.facebook.com/LEGO/videos/4092026577553489/)

Answer (score 0):

The Brothers Brick just published **another** [unofficial build](https://www.brothers-brick.com/2021/05/25/11-12-grimmauld-place-transforming-harry-potter-build/).

Comment: This might be better edited into your [original answer](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/15908/56) ;)

Comment: I intentionally didn't do that, because they were totally independent builds, of totally different styles, months apart.